# LookUpEdit DropDown background rows

Tags: c#, devexpress

Доброго времени суток.

А подскажите, пожалуйста, как в lookupedit сделать разный background color строкам выпадающего списка?
Например, в dropdown в первой строке в определённой колонке у меня значение "1", значит, background именно этой строке делаем, допустим, красным. А во всех остальных строках, в которых значение !=1, оставляем, допустим, с белым background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Используйте **GridLookUpEdit** вместо LookUpEdit. У него в попап окне лежит более функциональный GridControl, который поддерживает раскраску строк из коробки. Чтобы задать стиль, обработайте GridView.RowCellStyle event:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic

или используйте Format Conditions:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument759

Более детальную информацию можно найти здесь:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument758